# Change propery of control, that has a TwoWay binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a custom control with bool property. The property is binding include template control with Popup.

XAML control:

```
<controls:AutoCompleteTextBox x:Name="PART_Editor"
                              IsEnabled="False"
                              IsPopupOpen="{Binding IsAutocompletePopupOpen}" />
```

Property in the control:

```
        public bool IsPopupOpen
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsPopupOpenProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsPopupOpenProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPopupOpenProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsPopupOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(AutoCompleteTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Binding to element include in template control:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_AutoCompletePopup"
       IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I need change property IsPopupOpen on click. I decided to do this in behavior, but I need my control to be disabled. Therefore I was add behavior to container of control

```
<Grid>
    <controls:AutoCompleteTextBox x:Name="PART_Editor"
                                  IsEnabled="False"
                                  IsPopupOpen="{Binding IsAutocompletePopupOpen}"/> 
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:PopupContainerBehavior IsPopupOpen="{Binding IsAutocompletePopupOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

Behavior code:

```
public class PopupContainerBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
    {
        public bool IsPopupOpen
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPopupOpenProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsPopupOpenProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPopupOpenProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsPopupOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(PopupContainerBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));


        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseLeftButtonUp;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();

            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= OnMouseLeftButtonUp;
        }

        private void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            IsPopupOpen = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the property first changes to true and then immediately changes to false.Through SNOOP you can see this by the flashing value of the property.I think the problem lies in TwoWay Binding, but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is due to mouse capture.

- The behavior's `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event  handler tells the `Popup` to open
- The Popup captures the mouse
- The rest of the click events fire for the container
- The container takes away mouse capture from the `Popup`
- The `Popup` immediately closes

This can be a tricky problem to solve.

You might want to consider making your control able to open the `Popup` when it is disabled, vs. trying to do it from the outside. Even though a control is disabled, you can make parts of it clickable by setting `IsHitTestVisible` on the parts you need to be interactive, etc.